# How do I enable SHMConfig?

Tags: synaptics

I don't know how to enable SHMConfig on Ubuntu 12.04 so that I can run `synclient -m 100` correctly.

I searched and solutions were with HAL daemon, but I don't have HAL, I think it was deprecated.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Enter this command, it will give you access to change files on Nautilus

```
sudo nautilus
```

**Enter Password → File System → USR → share → X11 → xorg.conf.d →
 50-synaptics.conf**

Now you should see this text and find the part that looks like this

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
```

This option is recommend on all Linux systems using `evdev`, but you want to add `*Option "SHMConfig" "on"` under MathIsTouchpad "on" so it looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "SHMConfig" "on"
```

Save and exit and reboot.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the synaptics(4) man page, the `SHMConfig` option can no longer be used to configure the driver:

```
Option "SHMConfig" "boolean"
      Switch  on/off shared memory for run-time debugging. This option
      does not have an effect on run-time configuration anymore and is
      only useful for hardware event debugging.
```

The preferred way to configure input devices now is through the XInput extension.  The `xinput` command line tool provides one such way to do this.  You can get a list of the input devices on the system with the following command:

```
xinput list
```

Using the numeric ID of the touchpad, you can list its properties with:

```
xinput list-props $device_id
```

You can then alter properties with a command like:

```
xinput set-prop $device_id $property_id value
```

I am not sure which property corresponds to synclient's `-m` option, but if it is still available to tweak you should see it here.

Comment: *synclient -m 100* is supposed to update every 100ms, and show useful [or in my case, cool] information about the touchpad, like display the borders of edge scrolling, and live updating of touches on the pad.

Comment: SHMConfig is no longer needed to configure the driver, but it is needed if you want to see real-time debugging info, eg using `synclient-m 100`.  Adam's answer of setting it in an xorg config file worked for me.